# Simple JavaScript/jQuery sum function using bind

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML form that has multiple instances of doing a basic SUM calculation in different textboxes.  I don't have control of updating or rewriting the HTML.  I need a way to write a generic sum function that will "listen" for the change in any of the textboxes, do the sum, and output the result in those textboxes result textbox.

For example:

```
<input id="txtBox1"/>
<input id="txtBox2"/>
<input id="txtSumOfBox1AndBox2"/>

<input id="txtBox3"/>
<input id="txtBox4"/>
<input id="txtSumOfBox3AndBox4"/>
```

What I would like to do is "bind" or "listen" (I'm not sure which to use) that will "listen" to a change in "txtBox1" or "txtBox2", do the math and then output the sum into the result box, "txtSumOfBox1AndBox2".  It will do the same for boxes 3 and 4.

I could have 1 to many of these and they all need to use the same sum calculation and output to their respective result fields.

I could have an instance where I have the following as well:

```
<input id="txtBox5"/>
<input id="txtBox6"/>
<input id="txtBox7"/>
<input id="txtBox8"/>
<input id="txtBox9"/>
<input id="txtSumOfBox5Through9"/>
```

...and here is my javascript:

```
$('#txtProductAUsed,#txtProductBUsed').on('keypress change', {
  inputs: "txtProductAUsed:txtProductBUsed",
  output: "txtTotalUsed"
}, calc_sum);

$('#txtMixedInValue,#txtAmtNeeded,#txtLeftover').on('change', {
  inputs: "txtMixedInValue:txtAmtNeeded:txtLeftover",
  output: "txtTotalProduct"
}, calc_sum);

function calc_sum(event) {
  var sum = 0;
  var inputFields = event.data.inputs;
  var totalField = event.data.output;

  $.each(inputFields.split(':'), function() {
    sum += Number($('#' + this).val());
  });

  $('#' + totalField).val(sum);
}
```

I've read through the documentation on jQuery bind but it's not making sense to me on how to get the parameters I need.  I get the concept of looking for the 'change' event but not coding it to make it generic enough to accept any of the inputs.

**EDIT**
I played around with the "on" method and came up with this.

Here's the JSFiddle of my solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/mrhankuk/4ox7y1v1/1/

Comment: Look into the .on() method.  Bind is deprecated.  This may be challenging because you don't have a good way to identify the various textboxes.  You'll have to figure out how to identify all the input textboxes and the output textboxes by their (unique) id and then tie the inputs to outputs.  If you had classes to group inputs and outputs together you'd have a much easier time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED (for update the value when change the same input again):

So, I changed your way to listener your sum by selectors, so you can set on the array any selectors you want:

```
$.fn.sumListener = function() {
  var args = arguments;
  var $sumInput = $(this);
  $sumInput.prop("disabled", "disabled");
  for(i in args) {
    $(arguments[i]).on("change", function() {
        $sumInput.val(0);
        $(Array.from(args).join(",")).each(function() {
          $sumInput.val(+$sumInput.val() + +$(this).val());
        });
    });         
  }
};
$("#txtTotalUsed").sumListener("#txtProductAUsed", "#txtProductBUsed");
$("#txtTotalProduct").sumListener("#txtMixedInValue", "#txtAmtNeeded", "#txtLeftover", ".any");
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/diegopolido/sexd7b28/2/

I hope it helps

Comment: Excellent!  Much cleaner than my solution.  Thank you!